# Finding the error with library deducorrect in R

Tags: r

I was trying to filter data that is not correct in logical, so I wrote something like this,

```
#correcting
library(deducorrect)
u <- correctionRules(
  expression(
  if ( !(Species %in% c('setosa','versicolor'))) Species<- NA,
  if ( !(Sepal.Length > 0)) Sepal.Length<- NA,
  if ( !(Sepal.Width > 0)) Sepal.Width<-NA,
  if (!(Petal.Length > 0)) Petal.Length<-NA ,
  if (!(Petal.Width > 0)) Petal.Width <-NA,
  if (!(Sepal.Length <= 30)) Sepal.Length <-NA,
  if (!(Sepal.Length > Petal.Length)) Sepal.Length<-NA,
))
```

But, I got an error like this,

```
Error in correctionRules.expression(expression(if (!(Species %in% c("setosa"))) Species <- NA,  : 
  Forbidden symbols found
```

So how could I fix it, thank U!!!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find it explicitly in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deducorrect/deducorrect.pdf), but `%in%` seems to cause problems. The conditions in the rules need to be in some sense linear rather than arbitrary Boolean conditions.

Instead use

```
if ( !(Species == 'setosa' || Species == 'versicolor')) Species<- NA,
```

with everything else as before.